Angular 13, custom pipe in AppModule cannot be used in a SubModule
In my Angular application, I have a custom pipe, put it in "declarations" and "exports", in AppModule. I have a sub module "HomeModule", with a HomeComponent. Now, I use the custom pipe in HomeComponent, but got error "NG8004: No pipe found with name 'rootEmptyPipe'."
I know good practice is that to put this pipe in a "SharedModule" and import it in "HomeModule", but in my case, **at least now, I don't have "SharedModule". Please avoid go that direction at least for now. **
Sample codes below, Thanks!
I am expecting no error, because I believe the custom pipe defined in AppModule level, should be seen in sub modules.
- AppModule
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
.....
    HomeModule, <-------------------------- import HomeModule
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
  ],
  declarations: [RootEmptyPipe, <----------------- delare custom Pipe
TestComponent, 
AppComponent],
  exports: [RootEmptyPipe], <-----------------export custome Pipe
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}


- HomeModule

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
....
    TestPipeComponent, <------------------ component to test custom Pipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
....
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class HomeModule {}

- TestPipeComponent 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-pipe',
  template: `<h1>{{ 'Hello Home Test Pipe Component' | rootEmptyPipe }}</h1>`, <------ **error here!!!**
  styleUrls: ['./test-pipe.component.scss'],
})
export class TestPipeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private onDestroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}


  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onDestroy$.next(true);
    this.onDestroy$.complete();
  }
}

- RootEmptyPipe, only an example


@Pipe({
  name: 'rootEmptyPipe'
})
export class RootEmptyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): string {
    if (!value || value.length < 1) {
      if (args.length < 1) {
        return '-';
      } else {
        return args[0];
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}



You need to import pipe in module that you use. exporting pipe from AppModule probably doesn't have any effect.

@BojanKogoj, thanks for your quick reply, but in fact, I need to use this pipe in another sub module, that is why currently, I need to add it in AppModule. Still, for now, making a separate SharedModule is NOT an option ... history reasons.

In my case, i.e, using SharedModule is NOT an option for now, the solution would be, declare the custom pipe as standalone: true, then "imports" it in HomeModule.
Hope this could help someone else in the same situation.
Once again, "putting it in SharedModule" is the best practice, if it allows in your case.
